# Simple Navigation - Titanium

Tags: iphone, ios, navigation, titanium, appcelerator

I am an iPhone developer and a beginner in using Titanium. I have started learning Titanium few days back. I have worked on some basic samples which uses a window, views, button and button events. How can I use NavgationGroup? Can anyone say me how to navigate/push a new view when a button is triggered? Just I need to know the button event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already defined your navigation group like:

```
var first = Ti.UI.createWindow({
     backgroundColor:"#fff",
     title:"My App"
   });

   var navGroup = Ti.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({
      window:home
    });

    var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
       title: 'Open new window'
    });

    first.add(button);
```

Button listener will be like this where you can open a new window:

```
var second = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    background:"#fff",
     title:"Child Window"
});
second.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({text:"Here's the child"}));

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  navGroup.open(second);
});
```

There is a complete example related to your question [How-To: Create an iPhone Navigation Group](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2010/06/how-to-create-an-iphone-navigation-group.html). This may help you.